# reshaping specific rows Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I'm new in Matlab and I need to connect elements from two columns in different rows. I have the following matrix: 
a =

```
12    15
14    16
15    20
16    23
20    21
21    25
23    24
24    26
25    27
```

what I need is to identify the elements of the 2nd column that are equal to the elements in the first, and join them sequentially to create 2 rows : [12 15 20 21 25 27] and [14 16 23 24 26]. The actual data is quite large, so the more vectorized the code, the better!

Thanks for your help!
GIE

Comment: I have read this a couple of times and I still don't understand what you want. Do you want to *remove* the common elements from each column, then form two rows from the results of the compaction operation? What about cases where there is a many:one duplicate in either column, what should happen then?

Comment: yes, I want to remove common elements and then create the rows. If there were two equal elements in the same row, then this indicates that the sequence finishes there, and no more elements can be added afterwards.

Comment: Can't you just use `intersect` and isolate common elements, then subset `a` accordingly?

Comment: You are trying to find the components of a directed graph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883367/how-to-find-connected-components-in-matlab