# Grouping of points using Triangulation

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, delaunay

**Language** : MATLAB

**Problem Defenition:**

I have a set of 2D points in space. I would like to group the points based on their euclidean distance. My data has a property that two groups are always separated by at least R units. Hence for a given point, all points that are closer than 50 units can be considered to be its neighbors. Combining points having common neighbors would result in the groups (that is the idea at least).

**Proposed Method:**

Use delaunay triangulation in matlab and get list of edges of the resulting triangles. Remove all edges that are greater than R units. Each group of points left are the groups I am looking for. Remaining unconnected points can be ignored.

**Attempt:**
I tried to implement the above in MATLAB, but I am making a mistake in grouping the left over points. I am attaching my code.

```
DT      = delaunayTriangulation(double(frame(:,1:2)));
edgeList   = edges(DT);

edgeVertex1 = frame(edgeList(:,1),:); 
edgeVertex2 = frame(edgeList(:,2),:); 

dVec = edgeVertex1 - edgeVertex2;
edgeLengths = sqrt(sum(abs(dVec).^2,2));
requiredEdges = edgeLengths < NEIGH_RADIUS;

edgeLengthsFiltered = edgeLengths(requiredEdges);
edgeListFiltered = edgeList(requiredEdges,:);

% Clustering
edgeOrigins = edgeListFiltered(:,1);
edgeEndings = edgeListFiltered(:,2);
nodeList = unique(edgeOrigins);

if isempty(nodeList)
    Result = struct([]);
    super_struct(i).result = Result;
else
    groups = cell(10,1);
    groups{1} = nodeList(1);
    groupLength = 2;
    flag = 0;

    % grouping
    for j = 1:1:length(nodeList);
        neighbourList = [nodeList(j); edgeEndings(edgeOrigins==nodeList(j))];
        % add current node as part of neighbourList
        for k = 1:1:groupLength-1
           te =  ismembc(groups{k}, neighbourList);
           if sum(te) ~=0
                temp = sort([groups{k}; neighbourList]);
                groups{k} = temp([true;diff(temp(:))>0]);
                flag = 1;
                break;
            end
        end

        if ~flag
            groups{groupLength} = neighbourList;
            groupLength = groupLength + 1;
        end

        flag = 0;
    end

    largeGroups = cell(1,1);
    largeGroups_c = 1;
    for j = 1:1:groupLength -1;
        if ~ isempty(groups{j})

        for k = j+1:1:groupLength - 1
            te = ismembc(groups{j}, groups{k});
            if sum(te) ~= 0
                temp = sort([groups{j}; groups{k}]);
                groups{j} = temp([true;diff(temp(:))>0]);
                groups{k} =[];
            end    
        end

        % ignore small groups
        if length(groups{j}) > MIN_PTS_IN_GROUP
            largeGroups{largeGroups_c} = groups{j};
            largeGroups_c = largeGroups_c+1;
        end

        end
    end
```

in the above code, `frame` is the variable that has the list of points. The constants `NEIGH_RADIUS` represents `R` from the question. The other constant `MIN_PTS_IN_GROUP` is user defined to select the minimum no of points needed to consider it a cluster of interest.

When I run the above code, there are still instances where a single group of points are still represented as multiple groups.

[image: Result of running my grouping algorithm]

The red lines border a single group as identified by the code above. Clearly there are intersecting groups which is wrong.

**Question 1**
Can someone suggest a better (and correct) way of grouping?

**Question 2**
Any other alternate methods of obtaining the groups faster than Triangulation would also be great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know ahead of time how many groups there are?

Comment: No. The number of groups is unknown.

Comment: Build graph of edges of length smaller than `R`, get the connected components via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27890460/3139711).

Comment: @knedlsepp Your suggestion worked. Thank you. Getting the connected components was what I was essentially looking for. I am also interested in alternate approaches to the problem (i.e without using triangulation).

Comment: Maybe you could speed it up by using only the following edges: `edges = knnsearch(frame,frame,'K',2)` instead of the delaunay-edges. In terms of computational complexity however your delaunay-approach should be quite good already.

Comment: Ok. The above `knnsearch` approach is actually not a good idea, as this won't get you the correct results in most cases. If I can think of something better I'll write an answer.

Comment: @knedlsepp, I was about to say so

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of group you search for, you can use kmeans function in matlab statistic toolbox or you can find other implentation on matlab exchange ([kmeans clustering](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24616-kmeans-clustering))

Comment: In my case I do not know how many clusters/groups I have before hand.