# MATLAB: Finding strongly connected components in undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, matlab, networking, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a network (undirected graph), which is represented by the following sparse matrix:

```
 %  A B C D E F G H I J K L M
mm=[0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0; % A
    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0; % B
    1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0; % C
    1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; % D
    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1; % E
    0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1; % F
    1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0; % G
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1; % H
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0; % I
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1; % J
    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0; % K
    0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0; % L
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0; % M
   ]; 
xx=tril(mm + mm');
view(biograph(sparse(xx),[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','off'))
```

In this network, there are two strongly interconnected subnetwork: 
[image]

Are there some clever algorithm to identify such strongly connected subnetworks?

Please note that my matrix is rather big, ~10.000x10.000 entries, thus simple search algorithms might be too slow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think MATLAB has something inbuilt to do something like this but essentially what you are looking for is the Kosaraju Sharir algorithm which is the best known algorithm for finding strongly connected components. It is small and fairly easy to implement. Take a look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly the Kosaraju algorithm is for directed graphs only. However, my graph is undirected. And I didn't find any adaption for the undirected case. Do you have any solution for undirected graphs as well? Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand why this question is "put on hold". This is a perfectly valid request for help of finding a good way to solve a particular problem (which is described in detail, even with an image) using matlab. Can somebody (@adriaan Dan-Cornilescu aschipfl Himanshu bigOTHER) explain this to me please.

Comment: Also, the very good answer by randomGuy shows that the question was valid.

Comment: In the Bioinformatics Toolbox there is [graphconncomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html) that should do what you want.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883367/how-to-find-connected-components-in-matlab

Comment: Added `algorithm` and `graph-algorithm` tags. Feel free to revert if you don't think they're appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since this is an undirected graph there is no concept of strong connection. I was wrong in glancing over this important detail. Now, the two red circles are connected by a single edge and if we were to remove the edge from the graph the no. of connected components increases by 1(to 2). So given an undirected graph, the real question is "Does there exist an edge(or edges), removing which would increase the number of connected components ?". I can think of a brute force algo on the lines:

1. Remove an edge e between n1 and n2.
2. Is there still a path between n1 and n2 ?
3. Yes: This is not a candidate edge, go to 1
4. No: Good, removing this edge will break the graph, remove and go to 1

In the end the number of connected components would have increased by the number of edges removed. The complexity would be O(N*E) (O(N) for finding path between n1 and n2 after removing every edge). You may need to change your graph representation to do this effectively.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite clever (looking at the breaking of the graph by removing edges), haven't thoguht about that. I believe that can also be generalized for n-removed edges. Thanks!