# Splitting a set of points into subsets based on line segments

Tags: r, matlab, cluster-analysis, subset

I have a set of points and a set of line segments. I would like to split the set of points into subsets or clusters based on these line segments. Ultimately I am looking the the convex hull for each subset (the orange polygon shown in the figure on the right). Although the line segments in the example below are connected with one another, this is not always the case. I am guessing that the method should construct a convex hull from all points (orange polygon shown on the left), and then split the convex hull at the intersection point with the line segments, and somehow include the "inner" points in the new convex hulls (ie. points 1,2,3 and 4 in example below).

```
points = [-0.1325 -2.2267; -0.1525 -2.2267; -0.5319  1.0698; -1.3628 -0.1296;  1.7438  1.3784;  1.5770  0.9458;  0.5147 -2.6114;  0.8169 -2.2797; -1.0244  2.7143; -0.4422  2.8257; -1.7421 -2.4453; -2.4492 -0.4012]
linesegments = [-1.1258 -4.2270 -0.7196 -3.9662; -0.7196 -3.9662  0.4347 -0.4873; -2.3293  1.4275 -3.3717  2.2654; -2.3293  1.4275  0.4347 -0.4873;  1.3579  3.1700  3.3566  0.5079;  3.3566  0.5079  0.4347 -0.4873] % Each row is line with format [x1 y1 x2 y2];
```

[image: Fig 15 and 16.]

In this example there are 12 points and 6 line segments. Points 1 and 2 are positioned fairly close, but point 2 is slightly to the left and point 1 is slightly to the right. The convex hull of each subsets is:

```
ch1 = [9 10 5 6 3 9];
ch2 = [12 4 2 11 12];
ch3 = [1 8 7 1];
```

Comment: You might take a look at the `WhatIf` package and the related papers Not sure if they are directly applicable, but it is wort a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct lines between every pair of points. Find the intersection between these lines and the line segments (below I used [lineSegmentIntersect](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27205-fast-line-segment-intersection)). Disregard the pairs of points that intersect any of the line segments. Construct an undirected graph from the remaining pairs of points. Find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) in the undirected graph (below I used [conncomp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27890460/1053612) which is based on *Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition*). And finally compute the convex hull from the points in each connected component.

This Matlab function `convhullc(points, linesegments)` will find the coordinates of each convex hull.

```
function C = convhullc(pp, ll)    
    np = size(pp,1); % Number of points

    % Create line between all pairs of points
    combi = nchoosek(1:np, 2);
    ppxy = [pp(combi(:,1),:) pp(combi(:,2),:)];

    % Intersection between all lines and all line segments
    intersectpl = lineSegmentIntersect( ppxy, ll )
    % Pairs of points that do not intersect a line segment
    nointersect = (sum(intersectpl.intAdjacencyMatrix,2) == 0);

    % Creating adjacency matrix of points with no intersect 
    adj = sparse(combi(nointersect,1), combi(nointersect,2), 1, np, np);
    % Create undirected graph
    adj = adj + adj.'; %'
    % Find the connected components
    [nch, bin] = conncomp(adj);

    % Find the convex hulls
    ch = cell(nch,1);
    for i=1:nch
        if( sum((bin==i)) > 2 )
            ppx = pp((bin==i),1);
            ppy = pp((bin==i),2);
            K = convhull(ppx, ppy);
            ch{i} = [ppx(K) ppy(K)];
        end
    end
    ch = ch(~cellfun('isempty',ch));

    C = ch;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with any point. Label as A. Iterate over all neighbors. If you can reach the neighbor, label it as A, too. Proceed with the next point labeled A (unless it is exactly on a line). Once you have processed all A points, that part is complete. Start B on an unlabeled point.

Compute convex hulls afterwards.